# htaccess catch-all for Redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Note, from some searching I see that it's also possible to achieve redirects with `RewriteRule` rather than `Redirect` but I'm still curious to know why my catch-all isn't working with `Redirect`.

What I'm doing is redirecting various links on my site to a series of third party pages, and then using a catch-all to catch anything that isn't currently available under the `/help/` path:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
Redirect      302   /help/abc   https://example.com/help_pages/kKh6Sun7
Redirect      302   /help/efg   https://example.com/help_pages/jGut20m3
# catchall...
RedirectMatch 302   /help/.*    https://example.com/help_pages/default
</IfModule>
```

But even `mysite.com/help/efg` is being redirected to the catch-all.  I thought that these directives were processed in order, since they are part of the same Apache module and in the same context... see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#order)?

Comment: Did you turn on logging and examine the results

Comment: Do you have more rules in your .htaccess or just these 3 lines?

Comment: @anubhava yes lots more, but the fact is that if I comment out the catchall line then it works, but if it is uncommented it doesn't.  So that line is being reached despite `/help/efg` matching the earlier `Redirect` line first.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not sure how to do this

Comment: What happens when you remove the "lots more" lines? Is the above a [mcve]?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I reduced the .htaccess down to just three lines, wrapped in `<IfModule mod_alias.c> ... </IfModule>`, and the behaviour is still as stated.

Comment: Cool, just checking

Comment: @drmrbrewer: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 302 redirect URLs you get in chrome.

Comment: @anubhava good suggestion.  Do I look in the Network tab?  In that tab, I disabled caching, loaded the original URL, but I can't see where the redirect appears... it goes straight from the original URL to an element on the destination page with no apparent redirect inbetween.

Comment: Yes `Network` tab shows both original and redirected URLs.

Comment: First line has Request URL same as the original URL, with status code 302.  In the Response Headers it has a Location: which matches the *catch-all* rather than the *specific* redirect.

Comment: And if I comment out the catch-all line and reload the page, the Location is now the *specific* redirect.  So it seems quite simple: if the catch-all is there, that line is what determines the redirect.  Which shouldn't happen??

Comment: If you're able to try it, do you see the same?

Comment: I have already tried these lines in my local Apache but I cannot reproduce behavior.

Comment: Weird.  The host I'm using is on Apache/2.4.

Comment: Also in response header: `Server: cloudflare` and `X-Turbo-Charged-By: LiteSpeed`... would this have any impact?

Comment: I gave up.  Resorted to using `RewriteRule`, which works fine, including the catch-all.